# PyTorch RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Long

Tags: python, validation, pytorch, runtime-error, cross-entropy

I am trying to calculate the validation loss for my object detection model using Pytorch. My pre-trained model is faster rcnn. Below is the function I used to calculate the validation loss

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

def calculate_loss(model_outputs, ground_truth):
    # Extract the model's predicted outputs from the model_outputs dictionary
    predicted_boxes = model_outputs['boxes']
    predicted_labels = model_outputs['labels']
    predicted_scores = model_outputs['scores']

    # Extract the ground truth data from the ground_truth dictionary
    true_boxes = ground_truth['boxes']
    true_labels = ground_truth['labels']

    # Convert the predicted outputs to a tensor
    predicted_labels = torch.tensor(predicted_labels, dtype=torch.long)
    predicted_boxes = torch.tensor(predicted_boxes, dtype=torch.float32)
    predicted_scores = torch.tensor(predicted_scores, dtype=torch.float32)

    # Convert the ground truth data to a tensor
    true_labels = torch.tensor(true_labels, dtype=torch.long)
    true_boxes = torch.tensor(true_boxes, dtype=torch.float32)

    # Convert true_labels to one-hot encoding
    true_labels_one_hot = F.one_hot(torch.tensor(true_labels), num_classes=2)
    true_labels_one_hot = true_labels_one_hot.to(device=device, dtype=torch.float32)
    true_labels_one_hot = true_labels_one_hot.squeeze(1)

    # Only calculate loss for scores corresponding to true labels
    predicted_scores = predicted_scores[torch.arange(len(predicted_scores)), true_labels]

    # Compute the loss values for each component of the model
    loss_classifier = F.cross_entropy(predicted_labels, true_labels)
    loss_box_reg = F.smooth_l1_loss(predicted_boxes, true_boxes)
    loss_objectness = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(predicted_scores, true_labels_one_hot)
    loss_rpn_box_reg = F.smooth_l1_loss(predicted_boxes, true_boxes)

    # Return a dictionary containing the loss values
    loss_dict = {
        'loss_classifier': loss_classifier,
        'loss_box_reg': loss_box_reg,
        'loss_objectness': loss_objectness,
        'loss_rpn_box_reg': loss_rpn_box_reg
    }

    return loss_dict
```

When i try to validate my model, the system output the runtime error as shown below.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-ad31967ede1b> in <cell line: 3>()
      7     lr_scheduler.step()
      8     # validate on the val dataset
----> 9     validate(model, data_loader_val, device=device)
     10     # evaluate on the val dataset
     11     evaluate(model, data_loader_val, device=device)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction, label_smoothing)
   3027     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   3028         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 3029     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
   3030 
   3031 

RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Long
```

Why this error occur? How to solved it? As i can make sure, my true_labels_one_hot is type float32